# What note is this? And how would I got about working out what note I have sung in the future?

Tags: voice

I was wondering what highest note in this recording was?

I tried analysing using Audacity using the "Plot Spectrum" tool but I didn't really know what I was looking for.

I think it's G4 but I'm not sure.

http://vocaroo.com/i/s052qW8Wgs0G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first note is G4. The second note is highest and is A4 (or maybe a small amount flat of A4).

As for how to work out notes in the future, it's probably easiest to do it with an instrument (correctly tuned of course!) First, find out what the first note is, by finding the note that sounds the same on the instrument. Then listen for whether the music moves up or down for subsequent notes and work these out on the instrument, too.

BTW, I've posted this here to help you out, but this question will almost certainly be closed as being off-topic, as it doesn't really ask something that would be useful for future readers.